# jquery auto-change a drop down span

Tags: jquery, maps

I am using wxtiles for Google Maps. These are weather overlay tiles for Google Maps. This source includes a DateTimestamp in an HTML select that, when changed, will update the overlay tiles for weather forecasting. 
I am wanting to create a function that on page load, will automagically place these DateTimestamp values in an array and every 3 seconds, auto change this value which will then change the overlay tile. 
In short these weather overlays then 'behave' like animated KML files on google maps.
Here is an example from wxtiles:
http://www.wxtiles.com/

Here is the timestamp which comes from wxtiles:

```
var wxoverlay=new WXTiles();
wxoverlay.addToMap(map);
document.getElementById('tSelect').appendChild(wxoverlay.getTSelect());
```

And the HTML to display these timestamps.

```
<span id="tSelect"></span>
```

Is this idea possible due to the fact that these values always change, and come from a thirdparty? 
Thanks,